# Scheduled Force Restart Computer command not turning windows on its own

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-desktop

I am newbie to windows administration I want to set up windows startup script (bat) which should run after every restart so I have scheduled Force Restart Computer command in task scheduler to run for every 10mins but after restarting the startup script is not running (at blackbox considering not logged in with RDP session). So to check that I logged in via RDP on machine then windows is running that startup script consider RDP as new restart. I want computer should restart on its own and startup script should run at startup for every 10mins without logging via RDP. Please help me on this.

Task scheduler config:

Scheduled powershell  Force Restartcomputer command  with following General config.

[image]

Added startup script (.bat) script on the below path:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Expecting:

computer should restart on its own and startup script should run at startup for every 10mins without logging via RDP.

Comment: Did you check event viewer for any errors?  There is  delay option on startup processes and you may need to check the delay box.

Comment: No errors in event viewer. There is no delay given on task scheduler task. I am unable to see the startup sctipt running after rdp login. So task scheduler's restart command not restarted the windows machine. Do I need to check any win config here?

Comment: See : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/delay-start-programs/42a5e1c3-53f5-4763-897d-9aea3315db0e?force_isolation=true

Comment: As an aside: If what your script does is to _shut down_ the computer, then there is no way to run it _every_ 10 minutes - whenever it executes, there is by definition no _repeat_ run in the same session, given that the computer shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that your scheduled task runs at *system* startup - whether or not a user logs on - use an `At startup` trigger, as shown in this screenshot from the Task Scheduler GUI:

[image: "A Startup" trigger screenshot]

As you're already doing, this must be combined with the `Run whether user is logged on or not` option.